# pgmagick: Convert an image to PNG foramt

Tags: python, image-processing, pgmagick

I am trying to convert a jpeg image to a png(rgb+α).

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
img.write('path/to/file/png32:filename.png')
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
img.write('PNG32:path/to/file/filename.png')
```